# seeking jQuery Resources

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and I'm looking for somewhere to get started.  Specifically, I'm trying to get a plugin to work that allows sorting, pagination and filtering on an HTML table. If any one could point me to some useful resources for beginners and/or to assist with my task, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) is a very good plugin for this purpose. I'm currently using it for some small projects, and have found the documentation to be pretty good.

Comment: I saw that and thought it seemed like a great solution, however I wasn't able to get it working.  Can you tell me if it seems I'm doing anything wrong at a glance?  I have added the .js files to my solution and references them in my code, as well as the latest jquery library.  Within my HTML page I'm using $(document).ready(function(){
$('#mainTable').dataTable();
}); to kick it off, but I keep receiving an error like dataTable() isn't a valid function.

Comment: Could you post the code on jsfiddle.com? That error usually means that the plugin wasn't loaded properly.

Comment: The specific error I'm currently getting is 'jQuery is undefined'

Comment: Are you including the jQuery JS file, in addition to the DataTables JS file?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sdM79/ the table is populated from an XSL transformation from an XML file, so there's no data to show.  lemme know if I should add anything else in there.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dutchie yea - I have included jquery.dataTables.js, jquery.dataTables.min.js, jquery.js, and jquery-1.4.4.min.js

Comment: You should have jquery-1.4.4.min.js and jquery.dataTables.min.js, in that order.

Comment: Include `jquery.js` and `jquery-1.4.4.min.js` before the datatable include if not already.

Comment: Thanks guys! I seem to be on the right track now

Comment: I got the pagination and the search in place.  (I have the show X entries at the top left and the "Showing 1 to 10 of 41 entries" on the bottom left and the search box at the top right.  However I don't see the pager on the bottom right as on their website.  Does this need to be added separately?  Also, the css they include doesn't seem to match what they have on the site.  I'm guessing you have to come up with your own snazzy css to make it look like that?  (Mine just shows up as a border-less table with some row-hightlighting)  Thanks